# Class Object inside Function Not Working (FPDF)

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm using FPDF (plus FPDI).

I have a code like this:

```
$pdf->setSourceFile("source.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$size = $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 1, 1, 5.4);
```

**Result:** Works fine.

But when I wrap the code inside a function:

```
function hello(){
$pdf->setSourceFile("source.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$size = $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 1, 1, 5.4);
}
hello();
```

**Result:**

```
Fatal Error: Call to a member function setSourceFile() on a non-object
```

For some reason, the $pdf object isn't working when inside the function.

Any clue why?

Comment: ,Please check my answer for your solution. Let me know if you have still any issues.

Comment: Glad ! I could help to resolve your problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@qrafzvzv, You need to pass pdf object as a parameter inside your function.

```
For Example :

function hello($pdf) {
    $pdf->setSourceFile("source.pdf");
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $size = $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 1, 1, 5.4);
}
hello($pdf);
```